# Marking the suface on Plot3D

Tags: plotting

Is there any way to mark a specific line on the Plot3D graph in Log scale. My initial plot is:
`

```
Plot3D[(y/(0.5*y + 2*x)), {x, 1/10^10, 1/10^3}, {y, 0, 4.5/10^6}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

`
If is is not in Log scale,I know I can use ParametricPlot3D and use Show to overlay them together. But once I plot it in Log scale, ParametricPlot cannot show in Log scale.
What I would like to have is something like this:

```
    Plot3D[(y/(0.5*y + 2*x)), {x, 1/10^10, 1/10^3}, {y, 0, 4.5/10^6}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function @@@ {{{v, u}, v^3}}, Mesh -> 1, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Ticks -> Automatic]
```

`
However, since the MeshFunctions does not give a meaningful idea of what does the line stands for. Is there a way to just specify the X value to plot a line on that surface? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two coordinates passed to the mesh functions are the `Log` of the `x` and `y` values.  Here is the code for my interpretation of the intention of the OP's example `MeshFunctions` code (with a different value for the mesh line):

```
Plot3D[(y/(y/2 + 2*x)), {x, 1/10^10, 1/10^3}, {y, 0, 4.5/10^6}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{logx, logy, z}, Exp[logy]^3]}, 
 Mesh -> {{(5*^-7)^3}}, PlotPoints -> 100, Ticks -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my bacon! Now that makes perfect sense to me. Thank you for helping me out with this.

Comment: @ShawnYoung  You're welcome.